# "code": "6140" Duplicate Document Number Error

Tags: node.js, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am using QuickBooks. Somehow I am getting some weird error on creating one invoice.

```
{
    "Fault": {
        "Error": [
            {
                "Message": "Duplicate Document Number Error",
                "Detail": "Duplicate Document Number Error : You must specify a different number. This number has already been used. DocNumber=O0010714 is assigned to TxnType=Invoice with TxnId=45823",
                "code": "6140",
                "element": ""
            }
        ],
        "type": "ValidationFault"
    },
    "time": "2020-12-15T04:54:25.476-08:00"
}
```

Why it is happening as there is no doc in the QuickBooks which says that doc number is a unique entity.

Comment: Apparently QuickBooks thinks there is. Did you search for it? Have you tried creating this in the UI, to see if you get the same error?

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. Extremely sorry for the late reply. But I think there is an invoice already created with the same doc number. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short version:** DocNumber should be unique in most cases. In some cases you can add `include=allowduplicatedocnum` arg in URL to allow that. Be aware that DocNumber can be automatically generated.

**Long version:** taken from `DocNumber` [field documentation for Invoice](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/invoice)

> Reference number for the transaction. If not explicitly provided at
> create time, this field is populated based on the setting of
> `Preferences:CustomTxnNumber` as follows:
>
> - If `Preferences:CustomTxnNumber` is true a custom value can be provided.
>   If no value is supplied, the resulting DocNumber is null.
> - If `Preferences:CustomTxnNumber` is false, resulting DocNumber is system
>   generated by incrementing the last number by 1.
>
> If `Preferences:CustomTxnNumber` is false then do not send a value as it
> can lead to unwanted duplicates. If a DocNumber value is sent for an
> Update operation, then it just updates that particular invoice and
> does not alter the internal system DocNumber.
>
> Note: DocNumber is an
> optional field for all locales except France. For France locale if
> `Preferences:CustomTxnNumber` is enabled it will **not** be automatically
> generated and is a required field. If a duplicate DocNumber needs to
> be supplied, add the query parameter name/value pair,
> `include=allowduplicatedocnum` to the URI.

*P.S. Late response, but may be useful for somebody in future.*

**UPD:**
Looks like library from `npm node quickbooks` doesn't support that natively. Because [method `createBill`](https://github.com/mcohen01/node-quickbooks/blob/master/index.js#L302) doesn't allow to provide any params to URI. Even [method `module.create`](https://github.com/mcohen01/node-quickbooks/blob/7f32c84a16257a03def68a9a826b4f012f84d955/index.js#L2338) have just hardcoded `url` variable without ability to provide nothing extra.

In this case, if you still want to use `include=allowduplicatedocnum`, you have the following options:

- monkey-patch this library;
- make fork and do updates;
- ask authors of that library to implement that instead of you;
- find a library that will support that;
- send raw requests to QBO from your code.

Comment: Hi in which URI I need to pass `include=allowduplicatedocnum`? I am using npm node quickbooks ?

Comment: @Profer updated with details about library. In short - it doesn't support that. So you'll either need to go with another method, or patch library, or find another one, or send direct requests.